# Data and time conversion - PyMathematics

Tags: python, math

I am abit of a download freak. Most of everything i download is in gigabytes but is displayed in megabytes.

I would like to build a small python program that detects how long it is going to take for a download to finish depending on how fast the connection speed is.

I am terrible at maths, and i wouldn't know where to start in the algorithm.

It will have floating point numbers.. and i do understand that connection speeds can be very eratic at times, they may go up and down.. But it will be an approximation. I love maths, but floating point numbers are a great weakness.

It should go a little something like this:

```
fileSize: raw_input("How big is the file you are downloading? ")
conSpeed: raw_input("How fast is your current connection speed? ")

## Make sure fileSize and conSpeed are floats

print("Your download will finish in "+str(ALGORITHM_VAL)+" .")

# prints no more than 4 digits, not like 1 hour 23423432423424 seconds
```

Thanks for the help guys (and girls), much appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably first have to standardize on a unit of measurement.  Such as the file size should be in kilobytes, and the connection speed should be in kilobytes per second.  Otherwise, you'll have to parse what the user enters and convert to a common measurement.

Comment: i agree, i just tried googles seconds to minutes converter and its exactly what i DON'T want.

I can just see a whole bunch of if statements in this program.. Ergh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the two inputs are using the same unit of measurement, it should be a standard division operation:

```
size = raw_input("File size in KB: ")
speed = raw_input("Speed in KB/sec: ")
est = float(size) / float(speed)
print "It will take %f seconds." % est
```

Really, any time you see the word *per*, such as miles *per* hour or kilobytes *per* second, you can think of *divided by*: miles *divided by* hours, or kilobytes *divided by* seconds.

Now, if your file size input was in a *different* unit of measurement, such as megabytes, you'll need to convert that to a common unit of measurement first:

```
sizeInKb = float(size) * 1024
est = float(sizeInKb) / float(speed)
```

Lastly, you can easily display a time duration with Python by importing `datetime`:

```
print "Estimated Time: %s" % datetime.timedelta(seconds = est)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The basic equation to use will be: estimated_time = file_size/con_speed

Please ensure that toy have consistent units while computing. For example: if your connection speed in in Megabytes per second (Mbps) then the file size should also be in Mega bytes.

Normally 1 Gb is 1024 Mb or 1000 Mb (approx.)

For other  conversion rates please look at this chart:
http://www.wu.ece.ufl.edu/links/dataRate/DataMeasurementChart.html

Keep in mind that internet service providers normally use 1000 as the approximation unit rather than 1024.